# What music streaming services allow for radio broadcasting?

Tags: music, radio, licensing

I have a friend who works at a low-power, non-profit, community radio station. They already pay licensing fees to all the music licensing bodies, but we were discussing being able to use a streaming service to play music on the air. The streaming services we looked had a terms of service that only allow for personal use, which would make them incompatible.

Buying CDs or digital tracks is an expensive way of expanding the radio's music library. Is there a streaming source that allows for rebroadcast without purchasing each track?